# How many no-empty subsets of $(A \cup B)$are there?

Tags: logic

This is a Venn Diagrams homework. I don't understand why the answer to this problem is $511$. I know that $(A \cup B) - (A \cap B) = 7$.

> Set $A$ has $6$ members, set $B$ has $8$ members, and $A \cap B$ has $5$ members. How many non-empty subsets of $(A \cup B)$ are there?

Comment: Do you know how many members $A\cup B$ has?

Comment: How did you arrive to the conclusion that $(A \cup B) - (A \cap B) = 7$? This does not seem to be compatible with your other hypotheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$ (where $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of $A$)

So, $|A \cup B| = 6 + 8 - 5 = 9$

No of perfect sets (excluding null set) = $2^{|A\cup B|} - 1$

So the answer is $2 ^ 9 - 1 = 512 -1 = 511$